# How do you mark strings as "Safe" in a view (or the template) in Jinja2?

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

Typically when you want to mark string output as safe in Jinja2 you do something like this:

```
{{ output_string|safe() }}
```

However, what if output_string is *always* safe? I don't want to repeat myself every time by using the safe filter.

I have a custom filter called "emailize" that preps urls for output in an email. The ampersands always seem to become escaped. Is there a way in my custom filter to mark the output as safe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [Markup](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/documentation/api#jinja2.Markup) class:

> class jinja2.Markup([string])
>
> Marks a string as being safe for inclusion in HTML/XML output without needing to be escaped.

Answer (score 15):

Check [SafeString](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#filters-and-auto-escaping), like for example:

```
from django.utils.safestring import SafeString
...
return context.update({
        'html_string': SafeString(html_string),
})
```